# CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization errors with no known class method

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I just changed my target version for the app to iOS 8 and updated my XCode to 6.0 version. When I build I see a bunch of methods are getting marked as deprecated which confirms that I am actually building against iOS 8.0 but when I try to call [CLLocationmanager requestWhenInUseAuthorization], I get a build error saying
**No known class method for selector 'requestWhenInUseAuthorization'**

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`requestWhenInUseAuthorization` is an instance method, not a class method - create a `CLLocationManager` instance, and call the method on that.

See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestWhenInUseAuthorization) for more info.

Comment: Great. That worked. I was following http://matthewfecher.com/app-developement/getting-gps-location-using-core-location-in-ios-8-vs-ios-7 which incorrectly points to this function as a class method